ImportError: cannot import name 'play' from 'elevenlabs'
I'm trying to create my own voice assistant using elevenlabs to synthesize the voice.
I copied this code from elevenlabs api documentation:
from elevenlabs import play
from elevenlabs.client import ElevenLabs

client = ElevenLabs(
  api_key="YOUR_API_KEY", # Defaults to ELEVEN_API_KEY
)

audio = client.generate(
  text="Hello! 你好! Hola! नमस्ते! Bonjour! こんにちは! مرحبا! 안녕하세요! Ciao! Cześć! Привіт! வணக்கம்!",
  voice="Rachel",
  model="eleven_multilingual_v2"
)
play(audio)

But i got this error:
from elevenlabs import play
ImportError: cannot import name 'play' from 'elevenlabs'
Help me pls!

Do you have a directory or Python script named "elevenlabs"? If so, try renaming it to something else and rerun this.
